# What are roles and privileges to give a user in order to perform CRUD(on Oracle 12)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, toad

I'm creating a **USER** on **Oracle 12 c** database, using **TOAD**.

After creating the **TABLESPACE**, I'm creating the **USER**. I'm a little confusing about the many **ROLES** and **PRIVILEGES** that can be given to a USER.

What are the minimum/standard roles and privileges a user must be given in order to perform **CRUD** operation and being able to 'edit' the database (create or delete table, DROP the schema ecc) from TOAD?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what operations are you going to perform. If you want to work only with tables in your own db schema, then the following privileges are usually enough to start:

```
grant create session to <your_user>;
grant create table to <your_user>;
```

You have the default rights to insert/update/delete/select tables which you own.

Tablespace quota:

```
alter user <your_user> quota unlimited on <your_tablespace_name>;
```

It's better to set the default tablespace for the user. In this case you can omit the tablespace name in a create table statement.

```
alter user <your_user> default tablespace <your_tablespace_name>;
```

Answer (score 1):

A link to [the documentation - Privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTSQL/privileges.htm#TTSQL339)

---

Grant the user the following privileges:

- CREATE SESSION (in order to allow the user to connect to the database)
- INSERT
- UPDATE
- DELETE
- SELECT

---

Use the below command to grant privileges to the user (you need to login as SYS or SYSTEM or another user that has GRANT privilege):

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION, SELECT, UPDATE, DETETE, INSERT TO user_name
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suppose that, on TOAD, I have to select "insert any table", "delete any table", and of course create sequence. Is it right? For what concern the role , which one should I select?

Comment: I've updatet the answer, there is now a command which allow you to grant privileges there.

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, GRANT command you posted is 50% wrong. What is correct is `grant create session to user_name`. The rest doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: Thanks everybody :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion you might (or might not) want to follow.

As a privileged user (such as SYS), check tablespaces available in your database. I'm using 11g XE (Express Edition) which shows the following:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1        
TEMP            --> temporary
USERS           --> my data
```

Now, create a user:

```
SQL> create user mdp identified by pdm
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.
```

Quite a long time ago, there were two popular predefined roles named CONNECT and RESOURCE which were granted some of the most frequent privileges so people just *loved* to grant those roles to newly created users.

Nowadays, you shouldn't be doing that: grant only **minimal** set of privileges your user might need. The first one is `CREATE SESSION`; without it, your user won't even be able to establish a connection.

```
SQL> grant create session to mdp;

Grant succeeded.
```

Then, you'll want to create some tables so - grant it:

```
SQL> grant create table to mdp;

Grant succeeded.
```

OK, let's connect as newly created user and *do something*:

```
SQL> connect mdp/pdm@xe
Connected.
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test id values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> drop table test;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

Nice; I can create tables, insert/update/delete/select from them. For beginning, that's quite enough. However, when it turns out that you'd want to, for example, create a view, it won't work until you grant it that privilege:

```
SQL> create view v_dual as select * From dual;
create view v_dual as select * From dual
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL> connect sys@xe as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant create view to mdp;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect mdp/pdm@xe
Connected.
SQL> create view v_dual as select * From dual;

View created.

SQL>
```

And so forth; don't grant anything *just because you might need it* - grant it *if & when* you need it. Especially pay attention to system privileges which can potentially be dangerous if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: THank you again :)