# How to export schema and its data with TOAD

Tags: oracle, toad

On TOAD there are many options to export data.
[image]
What I want to do is to export a **schema/user** and its related object (**tablespace, sequences, etc**) in order to import it on another oracle installation on another machine.

Is there a specific option suitable for my goal?

Comment: Data Pump is a standard tool for these things in Oracle, but requires the server to have access to your export files (writes to a ALL_DIRECTORIES location). Try the Generate Schema Script option as a first stab and see what you get.

Comment: try take a look at export utility wizard

Comment: Hi @TenG, I already tried to use "Generate Schema Script". What makes me doubtful is that while reading the generated file,  I read something like: CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY 
ORACLE_OCM_CONFIG_DIR2 AS 
'C:\app\AB765CM\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1/ccr/state'; this URL refers to the computer where I'm copying the database from. I'm afraid this create a mess on the computer where I'm going to copy the database. It seems the script will create this folder

Comment: @scaisEdge I already looked at the "export utility wizard" but it's not clear which options to select then. "Export tables"? "Export users"? "Export this database"?
I suppose  "Export this database", but i'm afraid to mess up the new database, so before importing, I want to be sure I'm using the correct features

Comment: The script will not create that folder.USing your example, `ORACLE_OCM_CONFIG_DIR2` is the logical name for the physical OS directory `'C:\app\AB765CM\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1/ccr/state`. It will not, cannot create that physical drectory ... only when you run something that uses that will you get an error. If the target system must use a different path, you will to edit the script to change the path.

Comment: Ok, then ill try to log as SYS using toad, I'll copy the script inside the editor, I'll edit the  script according to the new machine environment and then I'll run the script

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it with TOAD, but from command prompt, using Data Pump Export and Import on command prompt. Here's an example.

First, as SYS, create a directory (Oracle object) which points to directory (folder) on my hard disk drive. Grant required privileges on it to user which will be using it.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> create directory my_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory my_dir to mdp;

Grant succeeded.
```

As MDP (it is user I created while answering your other question, here: [What are roles and privileges to give a user in order to perform CRUD(on Oracle 12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54500963/what-are-roles-and-privileges-to-give-a-user-in-order-to-perform-crudon-oracle)), create some objects:

```
SQL> connect mdp/pdm@xe
Connected.
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> create view v_test as select * From test;

View created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    select level from dual
  3    connect by level <= 5;

5 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

OK, operating system level, command prompt: export the user:

```
C:\>expdp mdp/pdm@xe directory=my_dir file=mdp.dmp log=mdp_exp.log

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Ned Vel 3 18:00:54 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Legacy Mode Active due to the following parameters:
Legacy Mode Parameter: "file=mdp.dmp" Location: Command Line, Replaced with: "dumpfile=mdp.dmp"
Legacy Mode Parameter: "log=mdp_exp.log" Location: Command Line, Replaced with: "logfile=mdp_exp.log"
Legacy Mode has set reuse_dumpfiles=true parameter.
Starting "MDP"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  mdp/********@xe directory=my_dir dumpfile=mdp.dmp logfile=mdp_exp.log reuse_dumpfiles=true
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 64 KB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/VIEW
. . exported "MDP"."TEST"                                5.031 KB       5 rows
Master table "MDP"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for MDP.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 is:
  C:\TEMP\MDP.DMP
Job "MDP"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at 18:01:24


C:\>
```

Nice; exported successfully.

Now, using SYS Oracle user, I'll drop MDP user; CASCADE is used because user has some objects which have to be dropped too. Why am I dropping it? To simulate your case, i.e. moving the DMP file to another computer/database which doesn't contain that user.

```
C:\>sqlplus sys@xe as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Ned Vel 3 18:02:32 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> drop user mdp cascade;

User dropped.

SQL>
```

Pretend we're now on another computer; first, I'm going to create the MDP user:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> create user mdp identified by test
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to mdp;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Back to operating system command prompt as I'm now going to import DMP file's contents.

```
C:\>impdp system@xe directory=my_dir dumpfile=mdp.dmp logfile=mdp_imp.log

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Ned Vel 3 18:09:47 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
Password:

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  system/********@xe directory=my_dir dumpfile=mdp.dmp logfile=mdp_imp.log
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
. . imported "MDP"."TEST"                                5.031 KB       5 rows
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/VIEW
Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at 18:09:51


C:\>
```

Import has finished successfully. Now I can use the MDP user with all its objects, e.g.

```
C:\>sqlplus mdp/test@xe

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Ned Vel 3 18:12:52 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select * from v_test;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5

SQL>
```

Don't forget what I said in another topic: grant MPD only privileges it needs. Currently, it can only create session and use existing objects, but can't *create* anything.

That's how it goes, more or less. Don't rely too much on GUI (you know how it is; *those who live by the GUI, die by the GUI*), clicking *here* and clicking *there*, hoping that something good will happen. Most probably won't. Though, once you know what you're doing, GUI is really a great help.